# Explain integer comparison with promotion

Tags: c++, integer-promotion

I'm trying to understand how integer promotion and comparison in a c++ application works.

```
#include <cstdint>

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t foo  = 20;
    uint8_t a = 2;
    uint8_t b = 1;
    uint8_t c = 5;
    
    if(foo == b*c) {}

    if(foo == a) {}
    
    if(foo == a + c) {}

    if(foo == a + b*c) {}

    return 0;
}
```

Only for the last comparison i get a compiler warning: "comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]".

Why does this only happen in the last case but not in the others?

Comment: `b * c`, `a + c` and `a + b*c` are all promoted to `int`s. Your compiler is only warning for one of them for some reason.

Comment: Which compiler, which version, and what command-line switches?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, this is reproducible in g++ 6.3.0 with `-Wall`. And also with g++ 7.4.0.

Answer (score 5):

since the type of operands are different a set of implicit conversions take place to reach a common type.

> For the binary operators (except shifts), if the promoted operands
>   have different types, additional set of implicit conversions is
>   applied, known as usual [arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) with the goal to
>   produce the common type (also accessible via the std::common_type type
>   trait)

because of integral types here **integral conversions** is applied to:

> - If either operand has scoped enumeration type, no conversion is    performed: the other operand and the return type must have the same
>     type
>
>   - Otherwise, if either operand is long double, the other operand is    converted to long double
>   - Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other operand is    converted to double
>   - Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other operand is converted    to float
>   - **Otherwise, the operand has integer type (because bool, char, char8_t,    char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t**, and unscoped enumeration
>       were promoted    at this point) and **integral conversions are
>       applied** to produce the    common type, as follows:
>   - If both operands are signed or both are unsigned, the operand with       lesser conversion rank is converted to the operand with the
>       greater      integer conversion rank
>   - Otherwise, if the unsigned operand's       conversion rank is greater    or equal to the conversion rank of the       signed
>       operand, the    signed operand is converted to the unsigned
>       operand's type.
>   - Otherwise, if the signed operand's type can represent all values of    the unsigned operand, the unsigned operand is converted to the
>       signed    operand's type Otherwise, both operands are converted to the
>       unsigned    counterpart of the signed operand's type.

The same arithmetic conversions apply to [comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) too.

from all this one can conclude since the `rhs` are all `uint8_t` the common type will be int, and then since the `rhs` is `uint32_t` the common type of `==` operator will be `uint32_t`. 
but for some reason that I have no idea `gcc` don't do the last conversion while clang does it. see the `gcc` type conversion for `+` operator in [godblot](https://godbolt.org/z/f3LZri) 
It also could happen that the warning is a false warning and the conversion took place, as it happened for `+` operator. 
See how `clang` sees the last `if`([cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=ICNpbmNsdWRlIDxpb3N0cmVhbT4KIC8vdXNpbmcgbmFtZXNwYWNlIHN0ZDsKI2luY2x1ZGUgPGNzdGRpbnQ%20CgppbnQgbWFpbih2b2lkKQp7CiAgICB1aW50MzJfdCBmb28gID0gMjA7CiAgICB1aW50OF90IGEgPSAyOwogICAgdWludDhfdCBiID0gMTsKICAgIHVpbnQ4X3QgYyA9IDU7CgogICAgaWYoZm9vID09IGIqYykge30KCiAgICBpZihmb28gPT0gYSkge30KCiAgICBpZihmb28gPT0gYSArIGMpIHt9CgogICAgaWYoZm9vID09IGEgKyBiKmMpIHt9CgogICAgcmV0dXJuIDA7Cn0=&insightsOptions=cpp17,all-implicit-casts&std=cpp17&rev=1.0)):

```
if(foo == static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<int>(a) + (static_cast<int> 
(b) * static_cast<int>(c))))
```

**Update:**

I couldn't find a difference in the assembly generated by the two compilers and would agree with @M.M so, IMO it's a `gcc` bug.

Comment: There is a difference between "not doing a conversion" and "not warning about doing a conversion".   The question only provides evidence of a lack of warning, not that the conversion is not being done.  To provide evidence the compiler is not actually doing a required conversion, it would be necessary to examine the output code (assembler, etc).

Comment: @Peter you are right the assembly must be checked. maybe the warning is a false warning. I edit my statement

Comment: Is not the big surprise here, that unsigned's are being promoted to signed's ? Without having a C++ lawyers degree, I would be tempted to say that this is the root problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a compiler "bug". To elaborate on this:

- In general, comparison between signed and unsigned relies on implementation-defined quantities (the sizes/ranges of types). For example `USHRT_MAX == -1` is true on common 16-bit systems, and false on common 32-bit systems. The answer by "oblivion" goes into more technical detail about this.
- All of your code examples are well-defined and behave the same on all (conforming) systems.

The intent of this warning is twofold:

1. to alert you to code that might behave differently on other systems.
2. to alert you to code that might not behave as the coder intended.

However, in general. it's not such a simple job for the compiler's static analysis to sort out the first case, let alone the second case which is rather subjective.

IMO the warning, for your code, is a bug because the code is well-defined and there is nothing to warn about.

Personally I don't enable this warning: I'm familiar with the rules for signed-unsigned comparison and prefer to avoid mangling my code to suppress the warning.

Going to the opposite extreme, some people prefer to avoid all signed-unsigned comparisons in their code even when it is well-defined; and they would consider it a bug that the compiler doesn't warn about your first three code examples.

GCC has tended to err on the side of warning too much, but they are in the situation that they can't please everyone.